# Mern Stack App - why doesn't the 'edit'-function work?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mern

guys. I'm having an issue with the 'edit' function. I always get an error, when I try to edit an entry. What could be wrong here? The Error says that something is wrong on the line 37, with "this.setState".

Here is the Error Message: [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYtng.jpg)

I really hope, that somebody can help me.
Thanks a lot in advance!

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';
    import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
    import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
    
    
    export default class EditUnterbegriff extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    
        this.onChangeOberbegriff = this.onChangeOberbegriff.bind(this);
        this.onChangeVorzugsbenennung = this.onChangeVorzugsbenennung.bind(this);
        this.onChangeDefinition = this.onChangeDefinition.bind(this);
        this.onChangeWeitere_Benennungen = 
 this.onChangeWeitere_Benennungen.bind(this);
        this.onChangeBetroffene_Kunststoffe = this.onChangeBetroffene_Kunststoffe.bind(this);
        this.onChangeAbgrenzung_zu = this.onChangeAbgrenzung_zu.bind(this);
        this.onChangeAnmerkung = this.onChangeAnmerkung.bind(this);
        this.onChangeDate = this.onChangeDate.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    
        this.state = {
          oberbegriff: '',
          vorzugsbenennung: '',
          definition: '',
          weitere_benennungen: '',
          betroffene_kunststoffe: '',
          abgrenzung_zu: '',
          anmerkung: '',
          date: new Date(),
          begriffe: []
        }
      }
    
      componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:5000/unterbegriffe/'+this.props.match.params.id)
          .then(response => {
            this.setState({
              oberbegriff: response.data.oberbegriff,
              vorzugsbenennung: response.data.vorzugsbenennung,
              definition: response.data.definition,
              weitere_benennungen: response.data.weitere_benennungen,
              betroffene_kunststoffe: response.data.betroffene_kunststoffe,
              abgrenzung_zu: response.data.abgrenzung_zu,
              anmerkung: response.data.anmerkung,
              date: new Date(response.data.date)
            })
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          })
    
        axios.get('http://localhost:5000/begriffe/')
          .then(response => {
             if (response.data.length > 0) {
            this.setState({
              begriffe: response.data.map(begriff => begriff.oberbegriff),
            })
          }
        })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
          })
    
      }
    
      onChangeOberbegriff(e) {
        this.setState({
          oberbegriff: e.target.value
        })
      }
    
      onChangeVorzugsbenennung(e) {
        this.setState({
          unterbegriff: e.target.value
        })
      }
    
      onChangeDefinition(e) {
        this.setState({
          definition: e.target.value
        })
      }
    
      onChangeWeitere_Benennungen(e) {
        this.setState({
          weitere_benennungen: e.target.value
        })
      }
    
      onChangeBetroffene_Kunststoffe(e) {
        this.setState({
          betroffene_kunststoffe: e.target.value
        })
      }
    
      onChangeAbgrenzung_zu(e) {
        this.setState({
          abgrenzung_zu: e.target.value
        })
      }
    
      onChangeAnmerkung(e) {
        this.setState({
          anmerkung: e.target.value
        })
      }
    
      onChangeDate(date) {
        this.setState({
          date: date
        })
      }
    
      onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        const unterbegriff = {
          oberbegriff: this.state.oberbegriff,
          vorzugsbenennung: this.state.vorzugsbenennung,
          definition: this.state.definition,
          weitere_benennungen: this.state.weitere_benennungen,
          betroffene_kunststoffe: this.state.betroffene_kunststoffe,
          abgrenzung_zu: this.state.abgrenzung_zu,
          anmerkung: this.state.anmerkung,
          date: this.state.date
        }
    
        console.log(unterbegriff);
    
        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/unterbegriffe/update/'+this.props.match.params.id, unterbegriff)
          .then(res => console.log(res.data));
    
        window.location = '/';
      }
    
      render() {
        return (
        <div>
          <h3>Edit Unterbegriff</h3>
          <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Oberbegriff: </label>
              <select ref="begriffInput"
                  required
                  className="form-control"
                  value={this.state.oberbegriff}
                  onChange={this.onChangeOberbegriff}>
                  {
                    this.state.begriffe.map(function(begriff) {
                      return <option
                        key={begriff}
                        value={begriff}>{begriff}
                        </option>;
                    })
                  }
              </select>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Vorzugbenennung: </label>
              <input  type="text"
                  required
                  className="form-control"
                  value={this.state.vorzugsbenennung}
                  onChange={this.onChangeVorzugsbenennung}
                  />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Definition: </label>
              <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  value={this.state.definition}
                  onChange={this.onChangeDefinition}
                  />
              </div>
    
              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Weitere_benennungen: </label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    value={this.state.weitere_benennungen}
                    onChange={this.onChangeWeitere_Benennungen}
                  />
               </div>
    
               <div className="form-group">
                 <label>Betroffene_kunststoffe: </label>
                 <input
                      type="text"
                      className="form-control"
                      value={this.state.betroffene_kunststoffe}
                      onChange={this.onChangeBetroffene_Kunststoffe}
                    />
                </div>
    
                <div className="form-group">
                <label>Abgrenzung_zu: </label>
                <input
                       type="text"
                       className="form-control"
                       value={this.state.abgrenzung_zu}
                       onChange={this.onChangeAbgrenzung_zu}
                    />
                 </div>
    
                 <div className="form-group">
                <label>Anmerkung: </label>
                <input
                       type="text"
                       className="form-control"
                       value={this.state.anmerkung}
                       onChange={this.onChangeAnmerkung}
                     />
                  </div>
    
                <div className="form-group">
                <label>Date</label>
                <DatePicker
                    selected={this.state.date}
                    onChange={this.onChangeDate}
                />
                </div>
    
            <div className="form-group">
              <input type="submit" value="Edit Unterbegriff" className="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
            </form>
           </div>
      )
    }
    }
```

Comment: are you getting all properties in reponse.data object ? i think you may not getting some of the properties in that object.. (oberbegriff, vorzugsbenennung,definition, weitere_benennungen, betroffene_kunststoffe, abgrenzung_zu, anmerkung)..

Comment: I am getting all properties, I just checked it. Any other idea?